# Post form receiving a model in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

For other hand i have the following view called Index:

```
@model List<Person>
@{

   foreach(Person person in Model)
   {
     <a href="#" id="@person.ID">@person.Name</a>
   }
}
```

Finally i have the following action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     List<Person> persons=new List<Person>();
     persons.Add(new Person(){ID=1,Name="John"});
     persons.Add(new Person(){ID=2,Name="Tom"});
     persons.Add(new Person(){ID=2,Name="Derek"});
}
```

Im thinking to create a form (since i cannot use ajax for this app due to some requirements), to post an instance of the person chosen by the user (when clicks an anchor of my view). I would like to know how i could post a Person instance to another action described below (since my view is typed to a generic list of persons).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
     ... Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Note on writing questions: please avoid adding "thank you notes" (upvote/accpt answers instead) and signature (you already have one in user name). 4 lines of thank you/signature don't bring much useful information to your question.

Comment: Hi Alberto, for this concrete project not.

Alexei, thanks for the remark i will take it into count from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution with POST:**

in order to work it with `POST` you will have to palce a form and plant hidden fields like

```
@model List<Person>
@{

   foreach(Person person in Model)
   { 
     <form action="/controller/actionresult">
     <input type="submit" value=person.Name />
     <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@person.ID"
     <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="@person.Name"
     </form>
   }
}
```

and on the server side

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
     ... Do whatever
}
```

**Solution with `GET`:**

`a` tags normally dont work with POST there default behaviour is to request the server for a resource via `GET` although you can override this behaviour using javascript but in your case that is not an option therefore you can try

```
@model List<Person>
    @{

       foreach(Person person in Model)
       {
         @Html.ActionLink(persno.Name,"Index","home",new{ID=person.ID,Name=person.Name,null);      
       }
    }
```

the only drawback is you will have to use a submit button instead of `a` tags, you can use css styling to style the button like an `a` tag. also if you have not set custom routes for this kind of request the uri will have query string params like

```
http://yourdomain/home/index?ID=1&Name=john
```

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching it from the wrong angle. As you're not presenting any way to edit a `Person` you should just pass it by reference (i.e. the `PersonId`).

So just use a straight-forward link:

// View:

```
Html.ActionLink( person.Name, "ViewPerson", new { personId = person.ID } );
```

// Controller action:

```
public ActionResult ViewPerson(String personId) {
    Person person = GetPersonFromDatabase( personId );
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know Dai, but in this case retrieving the persons is a tasks that spends a lot of load, so im searching a way to dont do another time the query. Thanks. Kind Regards. Jose